# Update in JPA with a char value of 6 bytes in database

Tags: java, jpa

I have a problem with updating an object using merge method. I try to update an object but it doesn't work, because update method seems to trim blank spaces.
So if i try to update an  object with a primary key like this: "24_ _ _ _ _ _ _" (blank spaces) with some blank spaces, it tries to update "24" without blank spaces, so that object doesn't exist and it doesn't work.
I can't modify my Entities because client does not allow us. 
I'm doing this with native queries, but i'd like to know if there is a way to update an object that contains a primary key with blank spaces.

When I call this method:

```
public Agend updateAgend(Agend agend ) 
    return em.merge(agend);
}
```

it does not update "24_ _ _ _ _ _"  with blank spaces which exists in my database.
it updates 24 and it doesn't consider my blank spaces. but 24 without spaces does not exist and it does not update anything.

Comment: It would be a good idea to include some code.

Comment: Actually i didn't face this kind of problem before, can you share which database do you use? Can you successfully update it with native sql? I mean database system allow it in native sql?

Comment: I'm using Oracle, and it works with a native query, but i'd like to use jpa